# Событие отрисовки GTK Widget

Tags: c, gui, gtk

Впервые столкнулся с мерцаниями при отрисовке. Стоит двойная буферизация. Перегружаю событие отрисовки виджета (GtkDrawingArea),

```
gboolean drawView_draw_event_cb(GtkWindow *window, CairoContext *cr, gpointer user_data){

    if(form->matrix==NULL)
        return TRUE;

    Draw_Matrix(cr);
    Draw_Points(cr);
    Draw_Path(cr);

    return FALSE;

}
```

получаю следующую картину:

[image: Мерцания]

Так же, видно что в конце точки вообще перестают рисоваться (а должен ещё построиться путь).

Далее, дёргаю фрейм, меняю его размер:

[image: Появляется исчезает картинка]

Как видно, в определённых позициях всё рисуется на ура, в некоторых, картинка вообще пропадает (видна отрисовка до команды Draw_Points(cr))

По процессу отрисовки, более подробное расписание методов:

```
void Draw_Matrix(CairoContext *cr){ // рисует на холсте матрицу

    DrawService.DrawMatrix(GTK_WIDGET(form->controls.drawView),cr,form->matrix); // рисуем матрицу

}

void Draw_Points(CairoContext *cr){ // рисует на холсте активные точки

    if(form->points->size==0)
        return;

    int pointIndex;
    ListItem *iterator = form->points->first; // перебираем "активные" точки

    for(pointIndex=1;pointIndex<=form->pointsCounter;pointIndex++){ // подсчитывает число отрисованных точек

        if(iterator==NULL){
            break;
        }

        PointEvent *event = (PointEvent*)iterator->data;
        DrawService.DrawCell(cr, event, form->timestamp); // рисует точку
        iterator = iterator->next;

    }

}

void Draw_Path(CairoContext *cr){ // рисует на холсте найденый путь

    if(form->shortPath==NULL) // если путь не был найден, выходим
        return;

    if(form->pointsCounter<form->points->size) // если не все точки поиска отрисованы, выходим
        return;

    PointEvent *event = (PointEvent*)malloc(sizeof(PointEvent));
    Path *point = form->shortPath;

    for(;;){

        if(point==NULL){
            break;
        }

        event->point.x=point->x;
        event->point.y=point->y;
        event->eventType=PATH_POINT;

        DrawService.DrawCell(cr, event, form->timestamp); // рисует промежуточную точку  найденного пути

        point = point->parent;

    }

    free(event);

}
```

А вот, непосредственно, сам сервис отрисовки:

```
void DrawService_DrawMatrix(GtkWidget *drawWidget, CairoContext *cr, Matrix *matrix){
    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint (cr);

    cairo_set_line_width (cr, LINE_WIDTH); // устанавливаем толщину линии сетки
    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09); // устанавливаем цвет линии сетки

    int x;
    int y;
    for(y=0;y<matrix->y;y++){
        for(x=0;x<matrix->x;x++){ // перебираем все прямоугольники внутри сетки

            DrawProperty property = DrawService_getProperty((char)matrix->data[x][y],0);
            cairo_set_line_width (cr, property.lineWidth); // устанавливаем толщину линии сетки
            cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, property.lineColor.r, property.lineColor.g, property.lineColor.b); // устанавливаем цвет линии ячейки поля

            DrawService_DrawRect(cr, x, y); // рисуем прямоугольник с соответствующими координатами
            cairo_stroke_preserve(cr);

            cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, property.fillColor.r, property.fillColor.g, property.fillColor.b);
            cairo_fill(cr);
        }
    }

}

void DrawService_DrawCell(CairoContext *cr, PointEvent *pointEvent, unsigned long timestamp){

    DrawProperty property = DrawService_getProperty(pointEvent->eventType,timestamp);

    cairo_set_line_width (cr, property.lineWidth); // устанавливаем толщину линии сетки
    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, property.lineColor.r, property.lineColor.g, property.lineColor.b); // устанавливаем цвет линии ячейки поля

    DrawService_DrawRect(cr, pointEvent->point.x, pointEvent->point.y); // рисуем прямоугольник с соответствующими координатами
    cairo_stroke_preserve(cr);

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, property.fillColor.r, property.fillColor.g, property.fillColor.b);
    cairo_fill(cr);

    printf("draw point [%d,%d]\n",pointEvent->point.x,pointEvent->point.y);

}
```

Далее, чтобы понять как это выполняется, создаю отдельный поток, делаю заморозку на 250млс. и с этим интервалом дёргаю "метод обновления" (как я понимаю, он ставит событие отрисовки в очередь событий gtk):

```
void redrawTaskRun(){

    form->pointsCounter++;

    if(form->pointsCounter>form->points->size){
        TimerService.Stop(form->drawTimer);
        return;
    }

    gtk_widget_queue_draw(GTK_WIDGET(form->controls.drawView)); // добавляем событие перерисовки в очередь

    char sizeStr[15];
    sprintf(sizeStr, "%d",form->pointsCounter);
    char str[64];
    strcpy(str,"Число уникальных путей ");
    strcat(str,sizeStr);

    char posStr[15];
    sprintf(posStr,"%d",form->points->size);
    strcat(str," из ");
    strcat(str,posStr);

    gtk_label_set_text(form->controls.lblToolTip,str);

    gfloat percent = (float)form->pointsCounter/(float)form->points->size;
    gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction(form->controls.progress, percent);

    while (gtk_events_pending ()) {
        gtk_main_iteration ();
    }

}
```

Извиняюсь за большой объём кода, в меньших масштабах подобное зафиксировать не получается.

С ГТК работаю относительно недавно, аналогичный способ реализовывал в java и c#, там это работает плавно, без каких либо рывков (хотя, имхо, тот же си, должен быть шустрее, а если и не шустрее, то никак не медленнее). Если кто сталкивался с подобным, или может объяснить что я не правильно сделал (или вообще, сам подход не верен в корне), пожалуйста, подскажите куда копать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основной момент , который нигде не указывается по gtk. Gtk библиотека "одного потока" и все функции `gtk_*` должны зарускатся в основном потоке , иначе поведение не предсказуемо.

В подобном случаи Я пользуюсь функцией

```
    g_timeout_add(timeout_show,function_show,data_show);
```

Эта функция в основном потоке не гарантировано , но старается запускает `function_show` через установленый интервал `timeout_show`. А уже в отдельном потоке, я формирую необходимые данные для прорисовки.

Comment: Спасибо за предложение. Подправил таймер, заменил pthread на g_timeout_add, сделал возвраты, как указано в доках [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KC4X8qpp) - результат ещё [хуже](https://i.gyazo.com/2ae16d91a0afa32cf73b23e83b6487b0.gif) о_О. Не хочет он по нормальному рисовать...

Comment: То есть пропадают отрисованые точки ?
 У меня В тестовой программе ничего не моргает .

Comment: Как в исходнике соединен сигнал `"show"` и функция прорисовки по таймеру ?

Comment: Как в исходнике соединен сигнал "show"<< Никак. Таймер посылает сигнал "redraw" (_gtk_widget_queue_draw_), gtk делает перерисовку в сигнале draw (который расписан выше). Если это возможно, могли бы вы показать свой вариант?

Comment: хотя, если вы об [этом](http://pastebin.com/AwcWrk60), то [тут](http://pastebin.com/fhR3b0xL) код обёртки таймера, [тут](http://pastebin.com/vPskXmgp) реализация

Comment: Вот такая тестовая [програмка](http://pastebin.com/U9Lvh81k)

Comment: Звучать будет бредово, но, причина была в элементарной вещи (facepalm). В вашем примере вы показали GdkRGBA. "Ошибка" крылась в том, что моё полотно не поддерживало альфа канал, в свойствах (мой метод getPtoperty() как раз вычислял альфу и промежуточные цвета относительно timestamp - это "время жизни точки"), все цвета ячеек, которые были с альфой (на самом деле, я писал плавное появление прямоугольников, затем, по истечению 10 сек., они должны были "померкнуть", дабы, было видно более новые слои путей), превращались в argb(0, *, *, *), что, собственно и "прятало" их. Насколько же это глупо)